Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm and inverse Jacobian/Hessian
Let’s say I have a function $f(p,q):R^{n+m}→R$, with $p∈R^n$ and $q∈R^m$.
I have a set of $q_{i=1,…,k},y_{i=1,…,k}$ and I want to find $p$ so I use the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm to resolve the minimization problem:
$${\min_{p}\sum _{i=1}^{k}[y_{i}-f(q_{i}|{\boldsymbol {p}})]^{2}\,}.$$
At the end I get:

My parameters $p$.
The Jacobian of $f$.
The Hessian of $f$.

What I’m searching for is the inverses Jacobians and Hessians, like how can I find:
$${\displaystyle J(f^{-1})={\begin{pmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial p_{1}}{\partial y_{1}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial p_{1}}{\partial y_{k}}}\\\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\{\dfrac {\partial p_{n}}{\partial y_{1}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial p_{n}}{\partial y_{k}}}\end{pmatrix}},}$$
and
$${\forall i=1,...,k, \displaystyle H_{i}(f^{-1})={\begin{pmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial p_{i}}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{1}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial p_{i}}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{k}}}\\\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\{\dfrac {\partial p_{i}}{\partial y_{k}\partial y_{1}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial p_{i}}{\partial y_{k}\partial y_{k}}}\end{pmatrix}},}$$
directly from what was computed in the first place?
Not sure for the Hessian, but at least for the Jacobian, I know the inverse function theorem states:
$$J(f^{-1})=\left[J(f)\right]^{-1}.$$
But how can I “trick” this problem to get a squared, invertible Jacobian?

Do you need these objects only about the minima or do you need some sort of routine that can compute them at an arbitrary point?

@whpowell96 only at the minima I guess. The exact question I'm trying to answer is like "what would be the new calibrated value $p$ if $y_i$ moved infinitesimally?"

I see. The term for this in the literature is sensitivity analysis. I don't think you need the Hessian for this, but you can proceed via the IFT to do something like this to get your answer I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835821/least-squares-sensitivity-to-data

Thanks a lot! But still I'm not sure of some things. This paper looks to be the closest to answer to my issue.
At the chapter 3 it writes $X(c,w): \mathbb{R}^{N+M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ but then eq $(11)$ (what I'm acutally interested of) writes $\partial_xC=-\left[\partial_c\Omega\right]^{-1}\partial_x\Omega$. But in my case it would be $c\in\mathbb{R}^M$, not $c\in\mathbb{R}^N$. $\partial_c\Omega$ is not invertible, it's not even squared...
Should I go with the pseudo-inverse of $\partial_c\Omega$?
